# Show only bluetooth system settings activity and nothing else

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

My question is similar to [Android Wifi Settings within app(Kiosk-sh app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626452/android-wifi-settings-within-appkiosk-sh-app/27815380#27815380) but for Bluetooth settings.

In short I have an app running in **Kiosk Mode** and want to show **Bluetooth settings**.

If I use

```
Intent intentBluetooth = new Intent();
intentBluetooth.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intentBluetooth);
```

Bluetooth settings are shown along with all other system settings (application manager, Wi-Fi etc.). I want to **limit user to only Bluetooth settings** and nothing else (like Wi-Fi in above answer).

`com.android.settings.bluetooth` package has 3 different activities but none of them suit my needs. Is there a way to get similar system activity for Bluetooth as there is for Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 0):

Code you are using is working just fine. It may depends on concrete implementation on device OS.